# How to let user pick file for upload in nativescript (tried nativescript-imagepicker but need also non-images)

Tags: nativescript, angular2-nativescript, filepicker

I'm trying to let user pick a file (from storage) inside my NativeScript app to later upload that file to a server, but I couldn't find any file-picker really working.

I've found out that [someway it should be possible](https://discourse.nativescript.org/t/filepicker-will-pick-different-types-of-docs-from-wherever-location-in-storage-internal-external/2814/9) to use [nativescript-imagepicker](https://market.nativescript.org/plugins/nativescript-imagepicker) for selecting any file type and get file path from there for upload. 
This would be great cause I could then use [Nativescript-Filesystem](https://docs.nativescript.org/angular/ng-framework-modules/file-system) for my purpose.
I create context this way:

```
let context = imagepicker.create({
            maximumNumberOfSelection: 1,
            minimumNumberOfSelection: 1,
            mediaType: imagepicker.ImagePickerMediaType.Any,
            mode: 'single'
          });
```

However I cannot select any file other than images on android (API 28) and from documentation "mediaType" is only for iOS.
Has anyone been able to make it work this way as reported in first link? Am I missing something?

Is there any other way I could try to accomplish my desired result? I've had a try also on [Mediafilepicker](https://market.nativescript.org/plugins/nativescript-mediafilepicker) but cannot use it because it gives me a lot of conflicts with existing plugins I need for my project.
Just need something simple for selecting a file, what's the best "*NativeScript way*" of doing this? (preferably working both on android and iOS)

Please let me know if you need other info and be patient, I'm kinda noob on NativeScript. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Media File Picker](https://github.com/jibon57/nativescript-mediafilepicker) is one good option, let's know what conflicts you are facing there.

If you prefer to do it on your own then you might need little bit knowledge on marshalling [Objective C](https://docs.nativescript.org/core-concepts/ios-runtime/Marshalling-Overview) & [Java](https://docs.nativescript.org/core-concepts/android-runtime/marshalling/overview). With Android, it's quite easy to throw an [Intent](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent) to pick any or specific type of files for you. With iOS you will have to use [UIDocumentPickerViewController](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uidocumentpickerviewcontroller?language=objc) to pick up the file.

Comment: Wow, what a quick answer! I'd prefer not to do it on my own (also I'm not able to do it yet...). MediaFilePicker had build problem caused by another plugin I use "nativescript-barcodescanner" that also use "nativescript-camera" with different version, for what I can understand. I cannot replicate specific error message now, but I will if it helps.

However MediaFilePicker has a lot of features I don't need, so I'd prefer if it exists a simpler solution.

Comment: A library always comes with different solutions for different scenarios. Media file picker is not a heavy plugin after all, you may go with that. Or writing an intent will be couple of lines and implementing document picker will be some 10s of lines of native code, but you would need understanding of native apis.

Comment: I've made MediaFilePicker work removing nativescript-camera. Only, I don't like it so much because in Android i get a list of all files I could upload (all at once) instead of navigating to one folder for selecting my file to upload (as ImagePicker).
I'll take your answer as correct and I'd like to thank you for your help here and everywhere around the web that helped me a lot with Nativescript :-)